# Transfer mp4 from temporary path to documents directory and play

Tags: ios, swift, avplayer

I am using a [library called Gallery](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Gallery) to select one video from Photos. Whenever a video is selected, I would like to play that selected video (silently) somewhere in my `UIViewController`.

The for this question relevant part of the plugin is the function `func galleryController(_ controller: GalleryController, didSelectVideo video: Video)` which is called when a video is selected. I initially tried using the [function which you'll find under this link (presented by the library)](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Gallery#video-editor) to test if it would work but nothing happened: No controller was presented. After having done some research I believed I needed to transfer the temporary file (found under `tempPath`) to the documents directory - which doesn't seem to work either. You'll find the code I am currently using below.

If I print `tempPath` (the temporary path) and `videoFileUrl` (the URL the file is supposed to be transferred to) I get the following URLs respectively:

**tempPath:**
Optional(file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D9B0DCB6-8F99-4284-9BFF-52A284C6F1AE/tmp/F3DC43D0-491A-4548-9960-D01686B54ACB.mp4)

**videoFileUrl:**
file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/D9B0DCB6-8F99-4284-9BFF-52A284C6F1AE/Documents/F3DC43D0-491A-4548-9960-D01686B54ACB.mp4

### Code

```
internal var gallery: GalleryController?
internal let editor: VideoEditing = VideoEditor()

func galleryController(_ controller: GalleryController, didSelectVideo video: Video) {
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    editor.edit(video: video) { (editedVideo: Video?, tempPath: URL?) in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let temporaryPath = tempPath else { return }

            let fileName = temporaryPath.lastPathComponent

            let fileManager = FileManager.default

            let videoFileUrl = try! fileManager.url(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false).appendingPathComponent(fileName)

            if fileManager.fileExists(atPath: videoFileUrl.path) == false {
                try! fileManager.copyItem(at: temporaryPath, to: videoFileUrl)
            }

            let player = AVPlayer(url: videoFileUrl)

            //print(tempPath)
            //print(videoFileUrl)

            let playerLayer = AVPlayerLayer(player: player)

            playerLayer.frame = self.view.frame

            self.view.layer.addSublayer(playerLayer)
        }
    }

    gallery = nil
}
```

Comment: 1. Are you sure the file actually exists at `tempPath`? 2. Why do you continue to use `tempPath` instead of the safely unwrapped `temporaryPath`? 3. Why do you try to copy the file instead of move the file?

Comment: @rmaddy 1. I don't know if it exists, not sure how to test if it exists either though because I am testing the app on my phone (no videos in the simulator). 2. Edited it, no change. 3. I might need to use `tempPath` later but it currently won't matter if I copy or move it.

Comment: You have code to see if the file exists at `videoFileUrl`. Add similar code to see if it exists at `temporaryPath`.

Comment: If I replace `let player = AVPlayer(url: videoFileUrl)` with `let player = AVPlayer(url: tempPath)` nothing happens, too. That's what I started with and why I assumed I would have to move it to the documents directory.